# MySQL: consulta el número total de alumnos y el de alumnas, como "Número de ALUMNOS" y "Número de ALUMNAS"

Tags: mysql, sql

Parto de una tabla llamada alumnos que tiene una columna llamada sexo dentro de ella tiene caracteres de tipo varchar M para mujer o H para hombre el caso es que me piden que cuente el número de alumnos y alumnas en columnas distintas

```
SELECT count(sexo like '%H%') AS 'Numero alumnos',
count(sexo like '%M%') AS 'Numero alumnas'
FROM alumnos
GROUP BY sexo;
```

me devuelve esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La cuenta está bien 17 alumnos y 7 alumnas pero no lo muestra como debería

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me temo que no sabes como funciona la [función `count()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/counting-rows.html). Dado que el operador `like` va a devolver verdadero o falso, y que ambos *cuentan*, tu sentencia es equivalente a esto:

```
SELECT count(1) AS 'Numero alumnos', count('X') AS 'Numero alumnas'
FROM alumnos
GROUP BY sexo;
```

Percibes que el resultado es *correcto* porque estas obteniendo dos filas, con un valor incorrecto en una de las columnas y correcto en la otra, es decir, ambas filas son incorrectas, y esto es porque en realidad la *cuenta* la está haciendo al agrupar por sexo (por eso obtienes dos filas, porque hay dos sexos), pero no es lo que tu quieres.

Para *contar* registros basados en una condición como la que planteas, en realidad lo que quieres hacer es, para cada fila, sumar 1 en la primera columna si es hombre, y sumar 1 en la segunda columna si es mujer. Para devolver 1 o 0 según sea el caso, podemos valernos de un `case`, o de la función `if()`

Usando case, la consulta, sería algo como:

```
select   sum(case when sexo = 'H' then 1 else 0 end) as NumeroAlumnos
       , sum(case when sexo = 'M' then 1 else 0 end) as NumeroAlumnas
  from alumnos
```

Como puedes observar, no he incluido ninguna agrupación, pues lo que buscas es que la consulta me devuelva una única fila con ambas columnas.

Si, por el contrario, dos filas son *buenas* para ti, puedes simplificar aún más haciendo:

```
select sexo, sount(1)
  from alumnos
 group by sexo
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias llevaba horas tratando de hacerlo con count

Comment: Me alegra ser de ayuda. Considera marcar la respuesta como aceptada, pues esto ayudará en el futuro a quienes lleguen aquí a identificar que la respuesta **si** fue de ayuda. Recuerda que en StackOverflow puedes saber, de esta manera, si hubo una respuesta útil y cuál es. Es muy útil cuando llegas aquí googlando un proximo problema. Esto no resta mérito a otras respuestas y en ocasiones habrá buenas o hasta mejores respuestas no aceptadas, pero si que ayuda. Si no sabes como aceptar una respuesta, haz el [tour].